# I am trying to put a list of countries in a .js file and export it for reuse. Getting errors

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I am building a react/material-ui site and want to create a countries.js file that has the following in it (as an example)

```
  export default const countryList =  [
  {
    "label": "United States",
    "value": "US"
  },
  {
    "label": "Afghanistan",
    "value": "AF"
  },
   ...
  ]
```

I want to be able to import this as follows:

```
import countryList from '/json/countries.js'
```

where countryList will be the array that I can map like countryList.map...

I keep getting a parsing error, no matter how I define the function.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: After an answer from Prachi below, I tried to export/import like this:

```
export const Countries = [
    {
      "label": "United States",
      "value": "US"
    },
    {
      "label": "Afghanistan",
      "value": "AF"
    }
]
export default Countries;
```

Then I import the file as follows.  My intellisense tells me I have the correct path because I can see 'json' folder name in my intellisense list when typing:

```
import Countries from '../../../json/Countries';
```

I still receive the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../json/Countries' in 'C:\projects\DoxaProject\DoxaUI\DoxaUI\ClientApp\src\pages\patientpage\forms'
```

Any help on solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please console like this ? `console.log('countryList',countryList,'type',typeof countryList)`

Comment: Where do you want me to put this?  in the countryList.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `default` export can only take an expression; `const` and `let` statements are not allowed.
For example:-
const MyComponent = () => {
return `<div class="foo">HI</div>`;
};
export default MyComponent;
You should write your code as:

```
        export const countryList = [
      {
        label: "United States",
        value: "US"
      },
      {
        label: "Afghanistan",
        value: "AF"
      }
    ];

export default countryList;
```

And import it as:

```
   import countryList from "./country";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Unfortunately, this did not work. I still receive a "Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../json/Countries' in 'C:\projects\DoxaProject\DoxaUI\DoxaUI\ClientApp\src\pages\patientpage\forms'" error.

Comment: Well, I found the problem thanks to Prachi.  I knew his code was correct, so I decided the problem might be in my import statement.

It turns out that vscode intellisense is WRONG.  Even though it gives me a list of folders , it is always ONE level off.  So instead of importing '../../../Countres', it should be '../../Countries'.  Shame on me for thinking vscode isn't buggy as heck still, after 20 freaking years.

Thanks Prachi!

Comment: Its my pleasure aava!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `package.json` file by typing `npm init` in your terminal and then adding `"type": "module"` in it.

Example package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "iDontKnow",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "blablabla",
    "main": "main.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```